# How do I change the Totem Videos program that I did not install?

Tags: totem

Totam Videos was installed prior to my receiving the new computer.  I need a plugin to make it work, but it doesn't tell me which one.  I cannot delete or reinstall Videos as an option. Can you help me to get it functioning? Thanks

Comment: Although you sated it as "Totem" question it has nothing to do with a specific program. Codecs are required for media formats support and due to licensing issues most of those codecs cannot be shipped in the Ubuntu installation media. They can be installed on demand, the package is `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: We need more information

Comment: I don't have much more information.  I need to be able to watch DVD's and cannot.  My Ubuntu has the Totem Videos program but needs plugins.  They don't tell me which ones.  Michael Bay, I will try what you said.  Not sure where to go from that entry...

Comment: I typed in the   ubuntu-restricted-extras but it came back as  command not found